# How to explain briefly the clock cycle after ADDM instruction(Assembly - MIPS Architectue)?

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-architecture

`lw ($t0), 8($s1)` (load word) reads data from memory and writes it in a register. A modified
version of `lw` is `addm` which reads data from memory like `lw`: e.g.
`addm $t0, 8($s1)` means `$t0<-$t0 + 8 ($s1)`.
How to know what happens in the clock cycle after applying this instruction? Unfortunately I couldn't find a good resource!

[image]

Comment: addm is not a real mips instruction correct?  so are you using it as a pseudo instruction and if so then look at the real instructions, if this is part of a class assignment to add an instruction, then look at how you added the instruction.

Comment: @old_timer addm is a modified version of lw.Which adds the value to stored value(sum)

Comment: I guess you are not understanding the point of my question.  First and foremost not being an instruction means it is implementation defined.  Second being mips which there have been millions of individual implementations means any real or not real instruction is implementation defined.  So please clarify the question so it doesnt get closed as too broad or some other reason.

Comment: That diagram shows the "normal" MIPS processor, not one with the custom addm. Since it just a normal MIPS processor, it really doesn't add any clarity to your question.  Further, you don't specify whether this is single cycle or multi cycle or pipelined, though the diagram is single cycle.

Answer (score 1):

An `addm` instruction has to add the result of memory read to a register's value, before writing the register.

Fundamentally, an adder must be placed after the data memory (to work on its output).  One of the inputs to the adder will be the result of the memory read, and the other will be the other register's value.

In `addm $t0, 8($s1)`, (like `lw`) register `$s1` supplies a value to the main ALU, while the sign extension provides the other value, 8, to the main ALU; the main ALU does addition in computing the addressing, and sends that address to the data memory for read.  However, the first difference is that `addm` needs to also source `$t0`, which `lw` does not (`lw` only targets `$t0`, whereas `addm` both sources and targets `$t0`).

That sourced `$t0` needs to be feed in to the new (above mentioned) adder for `addm` as one of its inputs, where the other input to this new adder is the data memory read value.

The result of the adder needs to be written to the `$t0` register.

You can see that for the 2nd operand to the main ALU, control signal `ALUSrc` chooses between `Read Data 2` and `Sign Extended immediate`.  For both `addm` and `lw` the control signal should be 1 to choose the sign extended immediate.

Let's further note that `Read Data 2` is forwarded to the `Data Memory` for the case of `sw` instruction b/c for that `Read Data 2` is the value to be written into memory (i.e. in `sw $t0, 8($s1)`, while `$s1` is used for address computation, `$t0` is not and instead forwarded to the `Data Memory` as the `Write Data`).

That line already has one split(fork, i.e. one output feeds to several inputs) so, would further split it and extend the new fork of that same line (from `Read Data 2`) to reach the new adder for `addm` placed after the `Data Memory`.

Then, the output of the new adder for `addm` needs to be spliced into the `Write Data` line of the `Register File`.

Whenever making splicing changes to the block diagram, we want existing functionality to continue as is and splice in new functionality that triggers only when we encounter the new instruction.  This idea of splicing is to cut a wire and insert another input, joining new functions in (like a new adder) under control of a new MUX, and that means new control signals going to the new MUX to switch between new behavior and existing behavior.  Here the switch is to choose between existing behavior and the output of the new adder for `addm`.

As an example of this, we can already see that `Write Data` for the `Register File` comes from one of two possibilities, which, under control of `MemToReg`, is either the ALU output, or `Read Data` from Data Memory.  Rather than a choice of two, `addm` adds a third choice, usually this would be done by simply having two regular MUXes (e.g. simply adding one more MUX), but it could also be done using a three selector MUX that chooses among ALU output, Data Memory read value, or new `addm` adder output, for that line reaching back to the register file.

---

The above goes to single cycle, which is what is shown in the diagram; there is virtually no way in single cycle to reuse the main ALU as that new adder, since the main ALU is already doing work every instruction.

In multi-cycle processor, we might reuse the main ALU instead of adding a new adder, by adding a new cycle for `addm`, such that the function of the new adder in single cycle was replaced by use of the main ALU, but in extra cycle after.

In a pipelined processor you'd again have difficulty using the main ALU since the overlapping execution of instructions means that the ALU is busy every cycle, so we could add a pipeline stage for a new adder, though that would slow down all the existing instructions in order to accommodate `addm`.

Comment: *slow down all the existing instructions* - An extra pipeline stage after MEM would probably only increase bypass-forwarding complexity, and possibly lead to stalls if you tried to use its result too soon.  It wouldn't even increase branch latency, because it's not between fetch (IF) and branch-decision (EX).  So it would increase the amount of non-speculative work in flight later in the pipeline, not yet committed via write-back.  And thus maybe increase interrupt latency by 1 cycle.  But "slow down" other instructions only applies to silly definitions of instruction timing like reaching WB.